# Update a dict with list values with another dict

Tags: python

The code below works. The question is if there is a better and more elegant (maintainable) way.

The task is to *update* a Python dictionary which values are lists with another dictionary with the same structure (values are lists). The usual `dict.update()` doesn't work because values (the lists) are replaced not updated (via `list.extend()`).

Example:

```
a = {'A': [1, 2], 'C': [5]}
b = {'X': [8], 'A': [7, 921]}
```

Using `dict.update()` would result in

```
{'A': [7, 921], 'C': [5], 'X': [8]}
```

But `A` should become `[1, 2, 7, 921]`.

Here is my working solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from typing import Any

def update_dict_with_list_values(
    a: dict[Any,list], b: dict[Any,list]) -> dict[Any,list]:
    """Update a dictionary and its list values from another dict."""

    # create a local deep copy
    a = a.copy()

    for key in a:
        try:
            # remove the list
            b_value = b.pop(key)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            # extend the list
            a[key] = a[key] + b_value

    # add the rest of keys that are not present in the dict to update
    a.update(b)

    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = {
        'A': [1, 2],
        'C': [5]
    }
    b = {
        'X': [8],
        'A': [7, 921]
    }

    c = update_dict_with_list_values(a, b)

    print(c)  # -> {'A': [1, 2, 7, 921], 'C': [5], 'X': [8]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid conditionals by using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). There is only one case: you want to `extend`-merge lists from the second dictionary, with the target defaulting to an empty list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Any, Iterable


def update_dict_with_list_values(
    a: dict[Any, list], b: dict[Any, Iterable],
) -> dict[Any, list]:
    """Update a dictionary and its list values from another dict."""

    union = defaultdict(list, a)

    for k, values in b.items():
        union[k].extend(values)

    return union
```

This assumes that you don't mind mutating the value lists of `a`, which is a risky assumption indeed. To avoid this you would deep-copy `a` first, via something like

```
    union = defaultdict(list, (
        (k, list(v)) for k, v in a.items()
    ))
```

Or, for a very different approach which is naturally immune to side-effect concerns,

```
return {
    k: a.get(k, []) + b.get(k, [])
    for k in a.keys() | b.keys()
}
```

Comment: Because I don't understand `defaultdict` at all I don't get its advantage in the current case.

Comment: @buhtz If you don't want `defaultdict`, you can use method `dict.setdefault` instead. That is, for a key `k` in `b`, you can replace `if k in d: a[k].extend(b[k]) else: d[k] = list(b[k])` with the equivalent `a.setdefault(k, []).extend(b[k])`.

Answer (score 5):

Bottom line you need only 2 cases:

1. if a `b` key is present in `a`, merge values (extend for that matter)
2. if a `b` key is not present in `a`, then assign it to `a`

Assuming you're only expecting lists as values, you could write something like this:

```
def update_dict_with_list_values(
    a: dict[Any, list[Any]],
    b: dict[Any, list[Any]],
) -> dict[Any, list[Any]]:
    """Update a dictionary and its list values from another dict."""

    for key, value in b.items():
        if key in a:
            a[key].extend(value)
        else:
            a[key] = value

    return a
```

I would recommend avoiding single-letter variable names!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Mhm... The code is easier to read but less efficient because of if statements. I tried to avoid them. And I would hypotize that in a short function like this it is acceptable.

Comment: @buhtz Why do you think it's less efficient? Exception handling tends to be much slower than conditionals.

Comment: But exception only need to be _handled_ when they occur not earlier.

Comment: You do not need two cases.

Comment: Note that `a[key] = value` should probably be changed into the safer `a[key] = list(value)`, or `a[key] = value.copy()`, otherwise future modifications of`b` might result in accidental modifications of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [that answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278949/156357) I suggest a solution avoiding `if`. The key point here is that don't iterate over the dict to update (the target) but the dict that is updated with (the source).

```
def update_dict_with_list_values(
    a: dict[Any,list], b: dict[Any,list]) -> dict[Any,list]:
    """Update a dictionary and its list values from another dict."""

    for key, value in b.items():
        try:
            a[key].extend(value)
        except KeyError:
            a[key] = value

    return a
```

Comment: The `.copy()` function of a `dict` is *not* a deep copy, it's a shallow copy.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Just a typo. You are also able to edit and correct foreign answers by the way. ;)

Comment: The line `a = copy.deepcopy(a)` should probably be removed; or if you really want to have it, should should add a warning in the docstring explaining that `update_dict_with_list_values` will make deepcopies and discard the original objects in `a`.

Comment: You are right. Using a copy would be more a `join_dict_with_list_values()` then `update...()`.

Comment: Yes; but even for a `join` function, you should probably just write `a = {k: list(v) for k,v in a.items()}` rather than `a = copy.deepcopy(a)`, so as to make copies of the lists without making deepcopies of possible objects in the lists. (Also, in this case I'd recommend calling the return dict `c = {k: list(v) for k,v in a.items()}` rather than giving it the same name `a`, which is confusing and hides the fact that it's a local variable)